# SQL GROUP BY - Check if column with different values has certain value

Tags: sql, group-by, boolean, aggregation, contains

I am new to working with SQL and I am not sure how to approach the following problem:

Imagine I got this table

```
User_ID | Operating System | LastSeen (containing some timestamps)
1       |  IOS             | hh:mm:ss   
1       |  AOS             | hh:mm:ss
1       |  Unknown         | hh:mm:ss
2       |  IOS             | hh:mm:ss
2       |  Unkown          | hh:mm:ss
3       |  AOS             | hh:mm:ss
```

UserID in combination with the OperatingSystem could be a primary key and is unique in each row

I want to get a user table (and therefore I wanna use group by User_ID) giving me the latest LastSeen Value (using Max(LastSeen)) as well as a boolean for usesAndroid and usesIOS.

so the result should look like

```
User ID | Using_IOS | USING_AOS | LastSeen containing Max(LastSeen)
1       | True      | True      | hh:mm:ss
2       | True      | False     | hh:mm:ss
3       | False     | True      | hh:mm:ss
```

Regarding the Using_IOS/Using_AOS columns, I am not sure how to get them in a group by, can I use sth like a contains or in function in a GroupBy for a column that contains multiple different values in a group?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does it mean when the same user Id has IOS and AOS, how do you expect to see that when grouping by UserID? Please include desired results!

Comment: Ye, I am sadly not the best in phrasing my questions properly, does the edit answer your question? :'D

Comment: As indicated in the description for the `sql` tag, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

You can group on the user ID and use `sum`:

```
select user_id, sum(OperatingSystem = "IOS") > 0, sum(OperatingSystem = "AOS") > 0, max(LastSeen)
from test group by user_id
```